# google earth engine API ee.Initialize() throwing an attribute error

Tags: gis, google-api-python-client, geemap

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use the geemap google API. However, when I try to initialise `ee` using `ee.Initialize()` my script throws an attribute error saying: `module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'`.

Prior to running this command I do run`import geemap, ee` as well as `ee.Authenticate()` and my authentication is successful. No errors of any sort so I am not able to understand what is going wrong here.

I would appreciate any and all help with this problem.

P.S: I ran `pip3 install geemap` in terminal before, so the library is installed on my system.

Comment: Some code would be helpful to answer this.